# How to add functionality to an object in PHP

Tags: php, oop, domain-driven-design

I am creating a web site that essentially sells advertising 'spots'. I.e someone can signup and buy a banner advert to be displayed on the home page, or they can buy an advert where they get their own profile page. My point being, although all adverts share common functionality, they do differ.

To accomplish this, my domain model looks like this: (simplified)

```
class Advert {

    protected
        $uID,
        $startTime,
        $traits = array();

    public function __construct($_traits) {

        $this->traits = $_traits;
    }

    public function getUID() { return $this->startTime; }
    public function getStartTime() { return $this->startTime; }

    public function setStartTime($_startTime) { $this->startTime = $_startTime; }

    public function save() {

        MySQLQuery 'UPDATE adverts SET startTime = $this->startTime WHERE uID = $this->uID';

        foreach($this->traits as $trait) {

            $trait->save($this->uID);
        }
    }

    ....
}
```

-

```
interface IAdvertTrait {

    public function save($_advertUID);
}
```

-

```
class AdvertTraitProfile implements IAdvertTrait {

    protected $url;

    public function getURL() { return $this->url; }
    public function setURL($_url) { $this->url = $_url; }

    public function save($_advertUID) {

        MySQLQuery 'UPDATE advertdata_profile SET url = $this->url WHERE advertUID = $_advertUID';
    }

    ....
}
```

-

```
class AdvertTraitImage implements IAdvertTrait {

    protected $image;

    public function getImage() { return $this->image; }
    public function setImage($_image) { $this->image = $_image; }

    public function save($_advertUID) {

        MySQLQuery 'UPDATE advertdata_image SET image = $this->image WHERE advertUID = $_advertUID';
    }

    ....
}
```

There are actually several 'AdvertTrait...' classes, all of which implement IAdvertTrait.

As you can see, if I create an advert like this:

```
$advert = new Advert(
    array(
        new AdvertTraitProfile(),
        new AdvertTraitImage()
        ...
    )
);
```

I can then do this:

```
$advert->save();
```

And all the required information will get saved to the DB by the Advert itself and each of its AdvertTraits.

Using this method I'm able to create different kinds of advert simply by passing in different 'traits'. However, to my problem - I've no idea how I should go about manipulating an Advert. As per the example above, there is really no point creating and advert and then immediately saving it.

I'd like to be able to this:

```
$advert->getStartTime(); # Works
$advert->getURL(); # Doesn't work of course, as the getURL method is encapsulated within a property of the Advert's 'traits' array
$advert->setImage('blah.jpg'); # Also does not work
```

**I'm not sure how to go about making these 'internal' methods accessible.**

I could just create a different 'Advert' class for each kind of advert i.e:

```
AdvertProfile extends Advert {

    $this->traitProfile = new AdvertTraitProfile();

    public function getURL() { return $this->traitProfile->getURL(); }

    ...
}

AdvertImage extends Advert {

    $this->traitImage = new AdvertTraitImage();

    public function getImage() { return $this->traitImage->getImage(); }

    ...
}

AdvertProfileImage extends Advert {

    $this->traitProfile = new AdvertTraitProfile();
    $this->traitImage = new AdvertTraitImage();

    public function getURL() { return $this->traitProfile->getURL(); }
    public function getImage() { return $this->traitImage->getImage(); }

    ...
}
```

But I feel this is going to get messy; I'd need to keep creating new 'Advert' classes for every combination of traits I need and each advert class would need to define its trait methods in itself so they can be called from an instance of the advert.

I've also messed with the decorator pattern; so instead of passing these 'trait' classes to the constructor of the Advert, I chain the decorators together like:

$advert = new AdvertImageDecorator(new AdvertProfileDecorator(new Advert()));

However this requires the decorators to be able to 'lookup' methods that don't belong to them using method_exists and call_user_func_array which just seems like a big old hack to me. Plus chaining a multitude of decorators together like that just grates on me.

I've also had a look at proper PHP Traits, but IMVHO I do not think they'll help me. For example, every AdvertTrait has a 'save' method, all of which need to be called at the same time. I believe a proper Trait would require me to pick just one 'save' method from one trait.

Maybe I should use plain old inheritance - but then I'd still be creating specific types of Advert, all of which ultimately inherit from Advert. However I believe this would cause further issues; i.e I would not be able to make a AdvertWithProfileAndImageTraits extend from both AdvertWithProfileTraits AND AdvertWithImageTraits.

Can anyone offer a proper solution to this conundrum? Perhaps there is another design pattern I should be using.

Thanks very much,
Dave

Comment: To the person who downvoted, if you give me a reason for it I'll happily edit my question if it is wrong in some way.

Comment: I upvoted. Those drive-by, "me too" dowvoters really tick me off. I am sure that they drive people away from the site. Now that you are back at 0 you might get some helpful answers, which I think you deserve as you posted so much code.  The only way to do better, IMO, is to publish your code at http://phpfiddle.org/ so that we can play around with it. Good luck!

Comment: @Mawg thanks for your kind comment; I figured as much that it was just some random <insert expletive here>.

Comment: And, look at that, you got back to plus one & an accepted answer. Glad to have helped a litte. I hope that you have much more success with S.O and also that you cna help others too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go for the **Decorator** approach.
An abstract `AdvertDecorator` class can look like this:

```
abstract class AdvertDecorator implements IAdvertTrait {

    protected $child;

    public function __construct($child=null) {
         if(!$child) {
             $child = new NullAdvert();
         }
         $this->child = $child;
    }

    /**
     * With this function all calls to non existing methods gets catched
     * and called on the child
     */
    public function __call($name, $args) {
         return call_user_func_array(array($this->child, $name), $args);
    }
}

/**
 * This class is for convenience so that every decorator 
 * don't have to check if there is a child
 */
class NullAdvert implements IAdvertTrait {

    public function save($_advertUID) {
        // do nothing
    }

}
```

*Instead of the `NullAdvert` class you can use a `BaseAdvert` class, which implements all of your basic advert logic (like you have done in the `Advert` class).*

Now all other classes extend from this `AdvertDecorator` class:

```
class AdvertProfile extends AdvertDecorator {

    public function getProfileURL() { ... }

    public function save($_advertUID) {
         // save own advert
         MySQLQuery 'UPDATE advertdata_profile SET url = $this->url WHERE advertUID = $_advertUID';
         // save advert of child
         $this->child->save($_advertUID);
    }

}

class AdvertImage extends AdvertDecorator {

    public function getImage() { ... }

    public function save($_advertUID) {
         // save own advert
         MySQLQuery 'UPDATE advertdata_image SET image = $this->image WHERE advertUID = $_advertUID';
         // save advert of child
         $this->child->save($_advertUID);
    }

}

class AdvertProfileImage extends AdvertDecorator {

    public function getProfileImageURL() { ... }
    public function getProfileImage() { ... }

    public function save($_advertUID) {
         // save own advert ...
         // save advert of child
         $this->child->save($_advertUID);
    }

}
```

You can use it like this:

```
$advert = new AdvertProfile();
$advert = new AdvertImage($advert);
$advert = new AdvertProfileImage($advert);

// save all advert components
$advert->save('uid');
// call functions
$advert->getProfileURL();
$advert->getImage();
$advert->getProfileImageURL();
$advert->getProfileImage();
```

This structure is IMHO **very flexible**. Every Advert Component can be added to the current Advert in arbitrary order. Futhermore you can extend this solution with the composite pattern and add a `AdvertComposite` so that you can group your components. You can even add multiple Advert Components of the same kind to one Advert (for this you have to change the methods a little bit).

Comment: Thanks very much for this; I'm going to implement it within my own code now. I'll post another comment and accept the answer once I get it all working.

Comment: I've got it implemented. This is indeed very flexible; what a great design pattern - I think my previous attempt to use decorators was wrong as this is working so well! Thanks very much!